How do I save chemical equations as an SVG so I can paste them into MS Word?
I have found out after plenty of googling how to make well aligned chemical formulas in LaTex.
This is what I have:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Calibri}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 \ce{
   Fe &+  H_2SO_4 &&-> H_2 + FeSO_4 \notag \\
   FeSO_4 + (NH_4)_2SO_4 &+ 6 H_2O &&-> (NH_4)_2Fe(SO_4)_2 * 6 H_2O \notag
 }
\end{alignat}

\end{document}

I am not too pleased with the arrows, but apparently changing them to something that ChemDraw does isn't that easy. I used \usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf{Arrow[length=0pt 4,width'=0pt 1]}{0.15ex}]{mhchem} before, but the arrows are Kite types and they aren't even equal when you render the thing.
The only reason I am using LaTex is that it has functions for aligning chemical equations at multiple points. What I need now is to somehow export these equations to SVG in such a way, that I can get two images with boundaries like these:

I know I am probably asking for a lot but I just don't know how to achieve results like these with ChemDraw and MS Word. Is this even possible?

You can save them as small PDF files and insert them as pictures in Word
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
        \ce{Fe +  H_2SO_4  -> H_2 + FeSO_4 }
\end{document}

-------------

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    \ce{FeSO_4 + (NH_4)_2SO_4 + 6 H_2O -> (NH_4)_2Fe(SO_4)_2 * 6 H_2O }
\end{document}




This code produces a reaction (the first one) with a preceding space to align the arrows
\documentclass[border=2mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \parbox{9cm}{\hspace{2.5cm} \ce{Fe + H2SO4 -> H2 + FeSO4}} 
    \parbox{9cm}{\ce{FeSO_4 + (NH_4)_2SO_4 + 6 H_2O -> (NH_4)_2Fe(SO_4)_2 * 6 H_2O }}
\end{document}

Compile the reactions separately and place the PDF files as a figure in Word

This would not produce the required whitespace in the beginning of the first, shorter equation that I would need to keep them aligned after import into word. But I think I can solve that with an empty text/or text that has a transparency of 100%. Basically you align invisible text in the first equation with FeSO4 in the second equation. Viola: You have the exact amount of whitespace you need.

If you want two separate figures, this will make it difficult to align the arrows with each other, for example.
The ways I know to align the arrows involve making a single figure with both reactions.
Have you tried making these reactions in Word using the "insert new equation" tool?

Doesn't that limit me to Cambria Math as the font though? I really do not like that font for chemical equations. I just know the shift+enter shortcut and then "align at =". That doesn't do multi-alignment like alignat does though afaik. I did find a workaround in ChemDraw though. It is not perfect, but it works: Align everything manually using Alt+shift+ctrl+L/R. Then add a white copy of FeSO4 (longer equation) to the shorter top equation. Group with ctrl+G and then copy+paste the equations into word. its not perfect but it's good enough for now.

see the update I made to my answer
